# Changing one property in a Sass variable with multiple properties

Tags: sass

I have a Sass variable `$box-shadow` containing the value `10px 10px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);`

I would like to define another variable `$box-shadow-alt` in which the `h-shadow` property (the first 10px in this case) should be an inverse of that in the original variable. Is there a Sassy way of changing just one property of a multi-property definition, without redeclaring the whole variable?

To demonstrate, this should be the end result:

```
$box-shadow:      10px 10px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
$box-shadow-alt: -10px 10px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable contains a list.  That means you can use any of the list manipulation functions to do operations on it.  The functions you're needing here are `set-nth` and `nth`.

```
$box-shadow:     10px 10px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
$box-shadow-alt: set-nth($box-shadow, 1, nth($box-shadow, 1) * -1);
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew there had to be a smart way to go about this, but couldn't spot it in the docs. Thanks!